# Open pdf attachments in pdf reader instead of Word online

Tags: list, pdf

Is there anyway to change the default pdf reader? When someone clicks on it from a Sharepoint list, it opens Word online, it takes ages to load. Is there anyway to download it or open it with any pdf reader?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always enable the feature "Open in client application", and set your default app as Acrobat reader.